# how content inset affects layout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

While working with UIScrollView, I noticed some weird behavior about auto layout and content inset; take the following code for example:

```
- (void) loadView
{
  UIScrollView * scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
  scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

  UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
  label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  [scroller addSubview:label];

  [scroller addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scroller attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:40]];
  [scroller addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scroller attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:20]];
  [scroller addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:240]];
  [scroller addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:44]];

  self.view = scroller;
  scroller.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0);  //this is the game changer
}
```

Without the last line that changes the content inset, the UILabel is at (40, 20) as expected. When altering the content inset, the label moved to (40, 108), instead of (40, 64); the top content inset is somehow doubled.
If the UILabel is created with set frame and without those constraints as:

```
- (void) loadView
{
  UIScrollView * scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
  scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(40, 20, 240, 44);
  UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
  label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  [scroller addSubview:label];

  self.view = scroller;
  scroller.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Then it behave as expected (40, 20) and (40, 64) depending on the content inset.

I checked with the documents and tried flipping some switches, but still can't figure out why.

BTW, that was the result from the IOS(6) simulator, I did not try it on device yet.

P.S.
Things appear as expected on simulator with IOS7, except the difference of the new status bar behavior.